# Open source antimalware software for macOS

Tags: open-source, security, antivirus, malware, macos

I'm looking for good categorically open source software for macOS.

I did not use the term "antivirus", because I refer to software that can protect not only from viruses, but also from other types of threats (trojans, ransomware and so on).

I found this: [Clamav](https://www.clamav.net), it's just an example, do you know it? If so, what do you think? Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A very popular package is Malwarebytes located [here](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/). I use it and it works fine. It's also free.

Comment: Please check your link, it gets a 404.

Comment: I just checked the link and it works fine for me. Took me to https://www.malwarebytes.com/v1/

Comment: This is not open source, just gratis.

Answer (score 0):

[https://sqwarq.com/detectx](https://sqwarq.com/detectx/)   What is it?

Let’s start with what it isn’t: it’s not an AV Scanner that wastes your system resources scanning harmless files. It’s not a ‘clean up’ app that pretends to speed up or improve your mac’s performance, and it’s not an uninstaller or app remover for other apps that leave around file litter.

It is, rather, a lightweight, on-demand dedicated search and troubleshooting tool, probably the fastest of its kind, that can identify malware, adware, keyloggers, potentially unwanted apps and potentially destabilising apps on a mac. It can also help you (or us, if you consult us), to identify unknown and novel threats through its Profiler and History functions.

Comment: Is it open source? The page mentions shareware.